# A (physical) string with a weight in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, box2d, game-physics, box2d-iphone

I'd like to implement a (physical) string with a weight in iOS, that reacts to accelerometer input and colides against the view bounds.

[image]

What is the simplest way to do this? I would prefer to avoid using external frameworks like Box2D, unless of course a native solution is too complicated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you need it to accelerate under gravity and bounce realistically  when it hits the edge, you'll need to use a physics framework (unless you feel like getting out a physics book and doing the equations yourself) as there's nothing like that built into UIKit.

I'd recommend you try [Chipmunk](http://chipmunk-physics.net/) instead of [Box2D](http://box2d.org/). I've found it easier to use with Cocoa as it's pure C and not C++. It also has an Objective-C wrapper, but the developer charges for it (the plain C library is free).

Here's a [simple iPhone Chipmunk physics example](http://charcoaldesign.co.uk/resources/physics.zip) I put together.

It uses the accelerometer and UIKit for drawing - just replace the crates with your own objects. (The accelerometer doesn't work in the simulator, you'll have to try it on a phone).

UPDATE: now you've added the image I realise you mean a bob on a string (I thought you meant a UILabel that falls around the screen, lol!). Here's [another example](http://charcoaldesign.co.uj/resources/physics2.zip) that includes a tether between crates. If you use this plus the [Chipmunk docs](http://chipmunk-physics.net/release/ChipmunkLatest-Docs/) you should be able to figure out what to do.

You'll need to attach one end of the string to a static object, or one with infinite mass (not included in my example).

If you want a realistic string, you'll need to break it up into several short constraints instead of just one long one, but I suggest you start simple if you've not got much experience with physics libraries.